# Java logic - strange things happening in while loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, while-loop, buffer

In the while loop below I am finding some odd behavior with the output. I have spent a few hours looking over it but I'm confused as to why it returns the way it does.

```
 while (true) {

            try {

                Log.d("DEBUG BT - BT Service", "IN CONNECTED THREAD RUN");
                  for(byte firstbyte : buffer){
                  int j = 0;
                  int nbytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                  //    int nbytes = mmInStream.available();
                       String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, nbytes, "ISO-8859-1");
                  firstbyte = buffer[j];
                      byte[] adjbuff;
                  if(firstbyte == 90){

                      adjbuff = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, 21);
                   Log.i("Buffer conditioning", "Solenoid syncbyte ran from Connectedthread");
                      mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, 22, -1, adjbuff).sendToTarget();


                      try {
                          Thread.sleep(1000);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                      Log.i("data incoming loop", "Break at if");
                      break;
                  }else if(firstbyte == -91){
                      adjbuff = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, 24);
                      Log.i("Buffer conditioning", "Sensor syncbyte ran from Connectedthread");
                      mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, 25, -1, adjbuff).sendToTarget();
                      try {
                          Thread.sleep(1000);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                      Log.i("data incoming loop", "Break at if");
                      break;
```

If `firstbyte == 90` is true then the code within that if block is looped 21 times.
If `firstbyte == -91` is true then the code within that if block is looped 24 times.
I doesn't seem like a coincidence that it loops exactly the number of times in the second parameter of `Arrays.copyOfRange()`, but the second parameter is supposed to specify position the last byte that I want to include in the array?

Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm out of ideas to troubleshoot this.

Comment: It's probably because you never increase `j`, so you always get the same byte

Comment: Also, you iterate over `buffer` with a variable named `firstbyte`, but then it is immediately overwritten by `firstbyte = buffer[j];`, where `j` is always `0`. I don't know exactly what `mmInStream.read(buffer);` does, but I assume that it reads data from the stream to your `buffer`object, which you are currently iterating over?

Comment: True, but buffer is dynamic and  gets updated every 1000ms from an inputstream. Its intentional to check at buffer position 0 for either of these byte values. If 90 or -91 appears at any position other than buffer[0] then that array of bytes is invalid and should not be used. Do you see any reason why the if block for each one gets run through it's corresponding copyOfRange int to parameter?

Comment: Consider this: What if `mmInStream.read()` was only reading one byte at a time? It would always return 1, and `firstbyte` would always be that most recently received byte. Thus if your BT device sent 21 "90s" in a row, or 24 "-91s", you would see the behavior you've described. The `for` loop would never execute a second loop, b/c it would `break` out every time.

Comment: You are correct, a bug in the firmware on the connected device was causing the issue. It was sending the data like this... byte1 \n byte1, byte2 \n byte1 byte2 byte 3 \n etc until it eventually sent the entire packet. It was an issue that only affected bluetooth comms on the device so when I tried to debug with usb on my pc I didnt see the issue. Thanks to all for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we can't know the entire behavior of the loop, b/c that depends on the dynamic behavior of your BT device (which we don't have access to). The data that device is sending is arguably the most important factor in anticipating what the loop does.

As you mentioned in the comments, the device is sending data in an unexpected way -- that is, chunks of ever-increasing length, always with `byte1` (90 or -91) at the front. Because your loop runs quickly compared to the speed of the BT link, it probably always happens to read `byte1` first. I expect that `mmInStream.read()` returns 1, then 2, then 3, and so on, for 21 or 24 iterations, until a full valid packet is sent. And this explains the behavior you saw.

In other words, the loop was doing exactly what you told it to do, but the device was doing something unexpected. And, once you were able to troubleshoot that, you found your problem.